Getting error while executing AWS glue job
Writing an AWS glue job to get data from s3 and load into rds, job fails with an error

Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o106.getDynamicFrame.
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException:
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3-bucketanme.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com:443

I tried creating various things like created nat, any help on this would be appreciated since I'm stuck on this issue

Seems like a network connectivity/security issue. Make sure to check the following:

Check if the bucket is available in the same region
Check if the role you use in your glue job has sufficient permissions to access s3 bucket (e.g. [this policy][1])
Check the VPC/Subnet configuration for your job and make sure it has access to internet.
List item

P.S These instructions were too long to be a comment, that's why I posted as an answer
[1]: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AmazonS3FullAccess.html
